# opencv: different ways to fill a cv::mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I know that for fill a `cv::Mat` there is the nice `cv::Mat::setTo` method but I don't understand why I don't have the same effect with those pieces of code:

```
// build the mat
m = cv::Mat::zeros(size, CV_8UC3);
cv::cvtColor(m, m, CV_BGR2BGRA);  // add alpha channel
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// this works
m.setTo( cv::Scalar(0,144,0,55) );


m = cv::Mat::zeros(size, CV_8UC3);
cv::cvtColor(m, m, CV_BGR2BGRA);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  this does NOT work
m = m + cv::Scalar(0,144,0,55)


m = cv::Mat::ones(size, CV_8UC3);
cv::cvtColor(m, m, CV_BGR2BGRA);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  this does NOT work
m = m.mul( cv::Scalar(0,144,0,55) );


m = cv::Mat::zeros(size, CV_8UC3);
cv::cvtColor(m, m, CV_BGR2BGRA);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  this works too!
cv::rectangle(tracks, 
              cv::Rect(0, 0, tracks.cols, tracks.rows), 
              cv::Scalar(0,144,0,55), 
              -1);
```

PS: I'm displaying those mats as an OpenGL alpha texture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess "not work" means that the output is not the same as using setTo?

1. When transforming with `cv::cvtColor`, the alpha-channel is initialized to 255. If you add or multiply anything it will stay at 255.
2. Why do you use `cv::cvtColor` to transform instead of just using `CV_8UC4` when creating the mat?
3. You can't use `cv::Mat::ones` for multichannel initialization. Only the first channel is set to 1 when using `cv::Mat::ones`. Use `cv::Mat( x, y, CV_8UC3, CV_RGB(1,1,1) )`.

Comment: great, it fully answers! are those behaviours on the documentation?

Comment: Apparently not, at least I can't find anything about it. For the alpha channel it makes sense to put it to 255 (opaque) so the colorspace transformation doesn't change how the image looks.

Answer (score 0):

For an aplha channel you need to use `CV_8UC4`, not `CV_8UC3`.